# How to make issue# mandatory in GIT while committing

Tags: git, github, git-svn

We are setting up GIT.  We want to make the user mandatory to enter the issue # in the beginning of comment.  LIke "Issue 3222: Fix for result variations".  Is there a way to configure some sort of regular expression so that this check is made before committing?

Thanks,
Satish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may take a look at [*pre-commit* hook](https://book.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks).

Comment: I also found in http://schacon.github.com/git/githooks.html.  Thanks anyway.  It helped.  Unable to mark answer accepted on my browser.  I accept the answer.